# Python: function that never dies

Tags: python

I am writing a long running function that should never die like this:

```
def immortal():
    try:
        # do something
    except:
        sleep(5)
        immortal()
```

In this way, if there is something wrong in between try...except, it would be caught, after 5 seconds of sleep, the functions starts again.

What I am worrying about is, since it's a long running function, if there are two many errors, won't it cause the try...except stack too deep, and lead to performance problem?

Am I doing this right? If not, what's the correct way?

Comment: Why not just put the try inside a loop instead of doing recursion?

Comment: if you get error, it will jump again and again to except block and call function, you need to provide some login to correct error, so it can execute statement on try block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional `else` when using try... except.

```
def immortal():
    while True:
        try:
            # pass or raise
        except:
            print('error')
        else:
            print('done')
            break
```

Comment: immortal doesn't need break :)